# Terraform azurerm role definition with email address

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm, azure-rbac

I am deploying resources to **Azure** with **Terraform**. I want to assign roles to AD users by using their email address. In the azurerm_role_assignment resource, only the object id of the user can be used. I have tried it with email but it logically fails.

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.example.object_id
}
```

With **az powershell**, the role can be assigned with the user's sign-in name : `New-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName <userupn>` .

Is there way to do it with terraform?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. The data **azuread_users** can be used as a solution:

```
data "azuread_users" "users" {
  user_principal_names = ["kat@hashicorp.com"]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rbac_wvd" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_users.wvd_user.object_ids[0]
}
```